# rbenv & ruby-build not showing the same list of version

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I'm trying to install the latest ruby version (ie. 2.1.1) with rbenv.

After upgrading brew, ruby-build and rbenv the available ruby versions differs.

Executing:

```
ruby-build --definitions
```

gives me (only versions above 2.0):

```
2.0.0-dev
2.0.0-p0
2.0.0-p195
2.0.0-p247
2.0.0-p353
2.0.0-p451
2.0.0-preview1
2.0.0-preview2
2.0.0-rc1
2.0.0-rc2
2.1.0
2.1.0-dev
2.1.0-preview1
2.1.0-preview2
2.1.0-rc1
2.1.1
2.2.0-dev
```

With RBenv:

```
rbenv install -l
```

gives me (only versions above 2.0):

```
2.0.0-dev
2.0.0-p0
2.0.0-p195
2.0.0-p247
2.0.0-p353
2.0.0-preview1
2.0.0-preview2
2.0.0-rc1
2.0.0-rc2
2.1.0-dev
2.1.0-preview1
2.1.0-preview2
```

What is happening here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you updated rbenv and the rbenv-build plugin to the latest versions?

I personally prefer doing that by browsing to their installation folders (`~/.rbenv` and `~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build`) and pulling the latest changes, as in:

```
git pull origin master
```

I personally see all rubies when asking for a list (including 2.1.1).

Comment: Thank you. That solved it :)
I guess I must have two version of ruby-build installed at different places.