# ruby-build: definition not found: 2.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rbenv

I want to install new version of ruby by `rbenv install 2.2.1`, but I get the error

```
ruby-build: definition not found: 2.2.1
 The following versions contain 2.2.1 in the name:
  rbx-2.2.1
  rbx-2.2.10
```

Could you please let me know how should I install version 2.2.1?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23517427/4240604) might help you. Just try to update ruby-build plugin.

Answer (score 23):

You should upgrade ruby-build to the latest version, ruby-build is an rbenv plugin that provides an rbenv install command to compile and install different versions of Ruby on UNIX-like systems.

Using Homebrew package manager:

```
brew upgrade ruby-build --HEAD
```

If ruby-build-HEAD already installed try reinstalling it

```
brew reinstall ruby-build --HEAD
```

You can look for the current stable ruby version number at:

https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/

Then use rbenv to see the upgraded list of available options:

```
rbenv install --list
```

Install latest stable version as below (replace 2.2.2 with your version string):

```
rbenv install 2.2.2
rbenv rehash
```

To list and verify all installed versions:

```
rbenv versions
```

To set as the global ruby version (in this case 2.2.2):

```
rbenv global 2.2.2
```

Hope this helps you and everyone else who faces similar situation in future.

Comment: Nice, I had a similar problem and 'brew upgrade ruby-build --HEAD' did the job! Thanks.

Comment: `brew upgrade ruby-build --HEAD` gave me an error message about `--HEAD`, but trying without it worked.

Answer (score 20):

Most of the answer here use brew command. So in case, you are on Ubuntu, then do these.

```
cd ~/.rbenv
git pull

cd ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/
git pull
```

Answer (score 20):

Just in case anyone else runs into this issue using the `asdf` package manager, simply update your plugins by running:

`asdf plugin update --all`

This will make sure you are on the latest version of `ruby-build`

Comment: Absolutely for asdf!

Comment: This worked great!

Answer (score 1):

Try to update your ruby-build manually from the repository by using this command:

```
/Users/your-user/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build && git pull
```

Replace "your-user" with your Mac User

Once you've done that you can run the install:

```
rbenv install 2.2.1
```

Comment: `cd ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build`

`git pull`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way if you're using Linux and have git installed:

`git -C ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build pull`

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded homebrew

```
brew update && brew upgrade
```

and then was able to upgrade to 2.2.1

```
rbenv install '2.2.1'
```

Hope this helps!